# Rigging Help. Need help understanding some basics

Tags: rigging, bones

So I really haven't tried to play with rigging much besides on weapons and have run into some trouble when trying to rig a full character.  The main problem I am having is that the mesh does not line up exactly with the bones even though the weight is 100%.

Here is a picture of the rigging in T-Pose:
[image]

And this is what happens when I try to pose it:
[image]

The second issue is that the upper leg and the lower leg become disconnected when moving.  Not sure if this is a product of the first problem or not. But in general I can't angle the upper leg without the lower leg getting out of alignment.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Uploading a .blend file to Stack Exchange would be a real help in diagnosing this prob :)

Comment: I am new to posting in stack exchange, where do I upload and link to a file?  Couldn't I just do it through dropBox also?